PayPal Status Pending (incomplete transaction) when paying via CiviEvent
I have noticed a weird behavior with PayPal.
When paying a CiviEvent with PayPal I do not get any confirmation mail and the Status is "Pending (incomplete transaction)" while the payment goes still through.
But when paying a donation with PayPal everything works fine. The status is Completed.
Does anyone have ideas what could be the problem? The Log does not give me any hint.
Thanks in advance.
Tested on CiviCRM 5.74.4
and payment processor PayPal Express.

This looks like a regression, quick around would be to move from Paypal express to Paypal standard
Issue reported at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5310

Thanks for your response and help. Unfortunately I can not move from PayPal Express to PayPal standard since it does not work properly in Germany either.

Do you need quick solution?

one organization that I am consulting has a registration process for a big event atm and if there is any quick solution, it would be great. If not, I have implemented a little workaround which at least lets us move forward.
